# Fabric.js - How to add Grouping and Ungrouping in FabricJS Angular?

Tags: angular, fabricjs

We are trying to develop a tool based upon fabric JS. Our issue is, we cannot group and ungroup the images in the Canvas. The fabric version we are using is `^4.3.1`. We went through these documents
[Fabric.js - How to set values for Multiple Active Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64938093/fabric-js-how-to-set-values-for-multiple-active-object)
, but we are not getting any result.

[image]

Relevant codes are given below,

**GroupAll** : While clicking this above Group all button, this thing fires which groups all active elements selected.

```
  groupAll(){
    if (!this.canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.canvas.getActiveObject().type !== 'activeSelection') {
      return;
    }
    this.canvas.getActiveObject().group; // this.canvas.getActiveObject().toGroup() is not working
    this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
}
```

**Code for Selection **

```
 mouseMove(e: Event) {    
    if (!this._isMouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    const pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(e);
    switch (this._selectedTool) {
      case DrawingTools.ELLIPSE:
        this.fabricShapeService.formEllipse(
          this._elementUnderDrawing as CustomFabricEllipse,
          this._initPositionOfElement,
          pointer,
        );
        break;
     
      case DrawingTools.LINE:
      case DrawingTools.DASHED_LINE:
        this.fabricShapeService.formLine(this._elementUnderDrawing as CustomFabricLine, pointer);
        break;
     // This below code is used for Selection, Is there any error here???
          case DrawingTools.SELECT: 
            this.canvas.discardActiveObject();
            var sel = null;
            sel=new fabric.ActiveSelection(this.canvas.getObjects(), {
              canvas: this.canvas,
            });
            this.canvas.setActiveObject(sel);
            // this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
          break;
    }   
  }
```

What we are missing, Kindly help us with relevant documentation.